# Can you combine multiple chart types in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a bar chart containing stock market data of the form Open, High, Low, Close by date. What I would like to do is overlay a line to the chart showing when and at what price I bought and sold the stock. Is this possible or do I have to stick with just adding more bars as the Buy/Sell data?

My input is a text file separated by commas of the format
Date, Open, High, Low, Close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would probably be easiest is to just add two columns to your CSV that can hold the price you bought or sold the stock for on a particular day (assuming you will only buy/sell once on any given day). Then you could just add another bar to the chart.

To add a line on top of the bar chart is possible, but it's a hack and will take some trial and error to get it to look right.

1. Add another line chart to your report with only the buy/sell data. Both axes will have to be identical to the bar chart.
2. When the lines look the way you want them to, go into Chart Options. Choose to not display anything (titles, labels, legends, grid lines, etc.). You'll also need to make the background transparent. Leave the border for now.
3. Make sure the line graph is in front of the bar graph. If it's not, right-click it and choose Move -> To Front.
4. Move the line graph so that its borders line up perfectly with the bar graph.
5. Adjust as needed.

I just did it this way and it seemed to work alright. CR doesn't have the most robust chart tools, so you may need to play with it... I had to set a background color and then set it back before it would actually turn transparent, for example.

One problem that you may run into is that your buy/sell data will be sparse compared to the general market graphs. Because of this, your line graph likely won't show every day, so you'll need to add rows for every day to that data source, even if the buy/sell data is null. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ryan, I appreciate your answer.

Comment: I was able to do as you said. I have two problems: 1) my scales do not match since my Buy/sell columns are sparse and I have selected auto adjust scale since I do not want it to use a default 0-X scale. 2) there is a slight mismatch in my overlap of the two charts on the axes which shows up as double lines. I plan to address this as follows, my first problem can be tackled if I add my min and max for that particular chart as another column (min/max) and put it as a part of the buy/sell line chart. I am using "break line for missing data". I will need trial for the second.

Comment: Hey Ryan, it's a great answer, but the question is still really hard to understand. Would you consider retitling it and editing the text? It'll help make the answer more valuable to others.

Answer (score 3):

May want to try http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=6187.

Worked great for me.